# How can we list 31 rows and then repeat at row one, and do this seven times?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to list dates in October, which is 1 to 31 days, and do this seven times. When I hit row 31, I want the list to start again at row 1. How can I do that?

I have an 'Output' sheet where I am trying to show my results and a 'Daily Forecast' sheet where the data sits. Let's say I have 10/1/2021 in cell FP394 and it goes down to 10/31/2021 in cell FP424.

How can I repeat the range of 10/1/2021 to 10/31/2021, seven times, stacking the next one under the prior one, all in one row? I tried Offset, Mod, and Row functions, but I couldn't get it working. It never goes back to the very first cell (FP394) after the 31st cell (FF424). I would like a formula solution, not a VBA solution.

Comment: What version of Excel are you working in?

Comment: I believe that `=1+MOD(ROW()-22, 31)` would get you the day (starting on row 394)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you can use `mod()` and `row()` to get what you are after:

```
=DATEVALUE("2022-10-" & 1+MOD(ROW()-22, 31))
```

That's assuming that your dates start on row 394. Adjust accordingly if that changes.

Comment: The number is right, like 1, 2, 3, etc. However, I am getting 1/1/1900. How can I get this into a date format? I have a sheet named 'Control' that has 10/1/21, 10/2/21, 10/3/21, etc. Can I somehow use the dates in the 'Control' sheet in this function? the 'DATEVALUE' sample that you shared did NOT work for me. I tried =TEXT() and that didn't work either.

Comment: Interesting. It worked fine for me and spit out 5 digit dates that I was able to format. Perhaps try a different format for DateValue() like: `DATEVALUE("10/" & 1+MOD(ROW()-22, 31) & "/21")` and see if that makes your version/international settings happy.

Comment: Also, perhaps `=DATE(2021, 10, 1+MOD(ROW()-22, 31))` would be cleaner?

Comment: The last option works perfect! Thanks so much!!